# Proving that $ I + aiS $ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $ S: \mathbb{C}^5 \to \mathbb{C}^5 $ be an hermitian linear transformation. I want to prove $ I + aiS $ is invertible where $ a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus\{0\} $.
Is my proof valid?

Suppose $ I + aiS $ is not invertible and therefore there exists a $ v \neq 0 $ such that $ (I + aiS)v = 0 $.

$ (I + aiS)v = 0 \Rightarrow (-I - aiS)v = 0 \Rightarrow -aiSv = v$, and therefore, $ 1 $ is an eigenvalue of $ -aiS $.

However $ (-aiS)^* = aiS^*=aiS=-(-aiS) $, which means $ -aiS $ is anti-hermitian, and therefore all of its eigenvalues are pure imaginary - contradiction.

Therefore, $ I + aiS $ is indeed invertible.

Comment: Looks good. You could also have concluded that $a^{-1}i$ is an eigenvalue of $S$ which too is a contradiction